# Call multiple functions onChange event -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component of Dropdown list.

When any of the list item selects, 2 functions needs to be called, which respectively do 2 things:

1. The value should be posted in a API
2. Also some other actions dependent of the Dropdown option select.

I tried both the functions one-by-one in the "onChange" handler, they works fine individually but when calling together, it messed up things.

My code until here looks like this:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("this is target's value: "+ e.target.value)
    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    let fd = new FormData();
    
    fd.append("value", e.target.value);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${api}/project/role`,
      data: fd,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(this.state)
      })
```

Render component as:

```
render() {
...
...
        <><div style={{height:'7px'}}>Select from options:</div><br/>
        <select value={this.props.role.prefer} onChange={(e) => this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value)} className="form-control">  //The function placed right now in onChange is a action reducer function.

...
...
}
```

Now in onChange I want to call handleChange as well to POST value in API. How can I achieve this? Appreciate any help!

Comment: yeah, it's a function. `(e) => {thing1();thing2()}` You can do whatever you want in it.

Comment: *"I want to call handleChange as well to POST value in API"* - It looks like your `handleChange` function is doing exactly that.  But your component isn't *calling* the `handleChange` function.  Have you tried calling the function?  What specifically failed?  What did you try and how did it "mess things up"?

Comment: Hi David,
I tried calling handleChange individually like ```this.handlechange```, which worked fine.

Then, calling them together as ```onChange={(e) => {this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value) ; this.handleChange}}```. When select any option it throws error as :```TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined```

Comment: Why such way? You could just put this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value) inside your handleChange function

Comment: @Ankzious: Well, `this.handleChange` isn't how you invoke a function.  But `this.handleChange(e)` is.  To explicitly call a function you need to add parentheses, and if you want to pass any values to that function you need to include those in the parentheses.  Not unlike every other function you're calling in your code...

Comment: Ahhh damn, silly me, why didnt it come to my mind. It worked now. Thanks David! 

Thanks Charles too for your time.!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the solution discussed in comment section:

Calling 2(or many more functions) simply make
`(e) => {thing1();thing2()}` as Charles suggested.

The answer to the problem above, which worked as suggested by David.
And on how to call 2 functions for the above problem is by taking the event for both the functions like:

```
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value) ; this.handleChange(e)} className="form-control">
```

Thanks guys for guidance. Appreciate the help!